# Setting DataSource in VB.NET

Tags: .net, database, vb.net, datasource

```
Dim inc As Integer
Dim MaxRows As Integer
Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim dbProvider As String
Dim dbSource As String
Dim dA As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
Dim dS As New DataSet
Dim SQL As String

Private Sub AbrirToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AbrirToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim ClikedOk As Integer

    OpenFD.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
    OpenFD.Title = "Ubica la base de datos"
    OpenFD.Filter = "Agenda|Agenda.mdb"
    OpenFD.ShowDialog()

    If ClikedOk = DialogResult.OK Then
        strFileName = OpenFD.FileName
        dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
        dbSource = "Data Source = Agenda.mdb"

        con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource
        con.Open()
        SQL = "SELECT * FROM Contactos"
        dA = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(SQL, con)
        dA.Fill(dS, "Agenda")

        con.Close()
        MaxRows = dS.Tables("Agenda").Rows.Count
        inc = -1

    End If
End Sub
```

What I want to do is this:
The user should press Menu Item and select the Data Base file, then the Data Source would be directed to where the user pointed the Data Base file. 
What should I put in the line "dbSource = Data Source = ..."? Access Data Base is .mdb because I got troubles using .accdb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
dbSource = "Data Source = Agenda.mdb"
```

to this:

```
dbSource = "Data Source=""" & OpenFD.FileName & """"
```

and that will point the `Data Source` to the file the user selected.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but that didn't work. In fact, if I even try to put OpenFD.Filename; it tells me that ";" doesn't go there.

Comment: @CamiloBloodstar, my apologies, I got my language mixed up. You're using VB and I put that `;` on there because I write primarily in C#. Regardless, you stated you wanted to get the path to the file the user selected - you simply need to append that to the `dbSource` with `OpenFD.FileName` - that doesn't change. Please see my edit, I've fixed the syntax error ***and*** I put double quotes in the string just in case the path has a space in it.

Answer (score 0):

Well you are in a bit of trouble there. [Jet drivers are 32 bit and need to be updated if you want to use jet to access databases in 64 bit windows](http://www.connectionstrings.com/Articles/Show/using-jet-in-64-bit-environments).

You could also configure your app to run in WoW64 mode to use 32 bit drivers.

if you have done something about making jet work, then you can do:

```
dbSource = "Data Source=" & OpenFD.FileName;
```

If you did not want to jump through the hoops of getting Jet to work, [then you can use the .Net libraries to connect](http://www.connectionstrings.com/access#net-framework-data-provider-for-ole-db) by changing:

```
dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
dbSource = "Data Source = Agenda.mdb"
```

To

```
dbProvider = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};"
dbSource = "Dbq=" & "Agenda.mdb;"
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Somewhy when I tried to install AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe it told me that I'm under a 32 bit environment (and I don't get it; I have Windows x64, Visual Studio x64 and Office x64). 
I tried both of your options and none of them worked fine. After I clicked the Ok button the data base doesn't load.
Thanks for your time anyway!